# Get first row in each group together with its details

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table as given below:

```
id   Branch           type
1    breakfast        xxxx
2    breakfast        yyyy
3    breakfast        zzzz
4    lunch            aaaa
5    lunch            xxxx
6    dinner           xxxx
7    dinner           yyyy
8    dinner           yyyy
```

`id` is a primary key and auto increment key. Now there are 3 types under breakfast , 2 types under lunch and 3 types under dinner.

I want to all the branches but with only one type or the first type alone to be selected.

How can we do this ?

For example i have to get the below result:

```
id   Branch           type
1    breakfast        xxxx
4    lunch            aaaa
6    dinner           xxxx
```

Comment: What if you had `1,breakfast,xxxx` as well as `2,breakfast,xxxx`?  Should _both_ rows be returned, or only the first of them? In other words, is the `Branch` to be unique to the output, or do you want all rows having the first `type` per `Branch`?

Comment: i want branch to be unique in the output ..and also i dont have same type for a branch ..

Comment: In your sample, you do have the same type per branch at `dinner,yyyy` so I wanted to clarify.

Comment: sorry that was my mistake

Answer (score 1):

`select id, branch, type group by branch order by id`

Comment: This will work, but only in MySQL as it exploits MySQL's uncommon and unreliable treatment of `GROUP BY` when columns in `SELECT` are not also grouped.

Comment: @php777 Know that this won't work on a server with the sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enabled (which it is by default from 5.7.5 but not earlier).

Comment: @php777 If the answer worked for you, consider marking it as accepted. Since you're a fairly new user maybe you're not aware of the option to mark answers as accepted. If you want to know more please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on [MySQLs strange handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) of the `group by` clause (which I believe is disabled in recent versions) then this will work in any ANSI SQL compliant database (including SQL Server which you tagged the question with):

```
select t.* 
from table t
join (
  select min(id) min_id, branch
  from table
  group by branch
) x on t.id = x.min_id and t.branch = x.branch;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03daa2/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT branch, MIN(id), MIN(type) FROM [Table] GROUP BY branch
```

Will rearrange your columns, but it should produce what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this using `min` and `group by` function like this:

```
select min(t.id) as id,t.branch,min(t.type) as type
from test t
group by t.branch
order by min(t.id);
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f822/3/0)

Comment: @jpw I thought the OP is looking for the lowest id and lowest type for each branch.

Comment: Maybe you're right; I read this part: _with only one type or the first type alone to be selected_ as meaning the row with lowest id, but the question isn't that clear.

Comment: @jpw Yeah, I didn't understand exactly what the logic was behind getting those desired rows. It could be possible that OP is seeking for what you described, then in that case this solution wouldn't work.